# Can one always interchange the order of a surface and volume integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solid-angle

Consider a continuous charge distribution in volume $V'$. Draw a closed surface $S$ inside the volume $V'$.

[image]

Consider the following multiple integral:

$$A=\iiint_{V'}   \left[      \iint_S   \dfrac{\cos(\hat{R},\hat{n})}{R^2} dS    \right] \rho'\ dV' =4 \pi\ m_s$$

where

$R=|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|$

$\mathbf{r'}=(x',y',z')$ is coordinates of source points

$\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$ is coordinates of field points

$\cos(\hat{R},\hat{n})$ is the angle between $R$ and normal to surface element

$\rho'$ is the charge density and is continuous throughout the volume $V'$

$m_s$ is the total charge inside surface $S$

---

Also consider the following multiple integral:

$$B= \iint_S        \left[    \iiint_{V'}     \dfrac{\cos(\hat{R},\hat{n})}{R^2}   \rho'\ dV'  \right] dS$$

where the symbols have the meanings stated above.

\begin{align}
B &= \iint_S        \left[    \iiint_{V'}  \rho'   \dfrac{\hat{R} \cdot \hat{n}}{R^2}   \ dV'  \right] dS\\
&=\iint_S        \left[    \iiint_{V'}  \rho'   \dfrac{\hat{R} }{R^2}   \ dV'  \right] \cdot \hat{n}\ dS\\
&=\iint_S        \mathbf{E} \cdot \hat{n}\ dS
\end{align}

---

Is $A=B\ ?$

i.e. **Is interchanging the order of surface and volume integration valid?** I know it is usually valid but my doubt is due to the following reasons:

1. In the surface integral of equation $A$, when $\mathbf{r'} \in S$, we can only use spherical coordinate system with origin at point $\mathbf{r'}$ (in order to avoid improper integral with limits). So while computing $A$, we cannot use only one coordinate system. Instead, **we have to use infinitely many coordinate systems.**
2. In the volume integral of equation $B$, for all $\mathbf{r}$, i.e. for all $\mathbf{r} \in S$, we can only use spherical coordinate system with origin at point $\mathbf{r}$ (in order to avoid improper integral with limits). So while computing $B$, we cannot use only one coordinate system. Instead, **we have to use infinitely many coordinate systems.**

> **Edit:**
>
> I know $\int \left[\int f(x,y)\,dx \right]dy = \int \left[\int f(x,y)\,dy \right]dx$ is true usually. Also, if in the diagram, if the volume $V'$ is contained within the surface $S$, then it is valid to change the order of integration. *But here the issue is a little different.* The surface $S$ is inside the volume $V'$  (please have a look at my diagram) and thus improper integral comes into play.
>
> While computing $A$, if we need to avoid improper integrals, we have no choice except to work with infinitely many spherical coordinate systems each having their origin at points $\in V'$.
>
> Similarly while computing $B$, if we need to avoid improper integrals, we have no choice except to work with infinitely many spherical coordinate systems each having their origin at points $\in S$.
>
> Then how is it valid to change the order of integration in this situation? That is, how can $A=B?$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is valid since the once a parametrization/coordinate system is chosen for both the surface and the volume, their integration bounds don't mix, if you treat the $r$ and $r'$ coordinates as really existing in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Hence [Fubini's theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fubini_theorem) applies, as long as the integrals don't diverge somewhere.

Comment: $(1)$ You said "once a parametrization/coordinate system is chosen for both the surface and the volume..." Please carefully look at the two reasons for my doubt (last two para in my question). I am not using one coordinate system. In order to avoid improper integral with limits and cavities, I am forced to use infinitely many different coordinate systems while computing both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Joe your "infinitely many spherical coordinates" comment makes no sense since that's how divergence theorem works on a theoretical level. Really think of this integral taking place in a higher dimensional fictional space, you will see the $r$ and $r'$ coordinates do split.

Comment: @Joe Another example: $\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x,y)dydx$ also integrates over infinitely many coordinate systems where the origin for $x$ changes location if you were to interpret it as two integrals on $\mathbb{R}$ with one dummy variable. But there is no confusion here: as long as the function is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, everything works out. In other words, don't overthink your procedure. If there is a simple, equivalent way to think of a problem, run with it.

Comment: Your example helped me to have an intuitive feel of your idea. In order to rigorously learn these ideas **which path shall I go?** I am currently taking [online real analysis course](http://www.infocobuild.com/education/audio-video-courses/mathematics/Mathematics-I-IIT-Kanpur/lecture-01.html). After this what course shall I take (books or videos) to rigorously clear these ideas? Please give a strong/helpful suggestion.

Comment: @Joe to be quite honest, I wouldn't know. I have never seen these ideas presented in formal setting before. Everything I have said comes from my experience and a little bit of logical deduction to make it rigorous on my own. That being said, the best thing you could do is gain some practical problem solving experience. That means familiarize yourself with counterexamples in analysis (an actual textbook in its second edition), practice a lot of multivariable calculus integrals (I used to teach it), and perhaps learn distribution theory and practice taking distributional limits from a PDE class.

Comment: Ok.... **One important question:** If I rigorously understand why $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x,y)\ dydx=\int_0^x \int_0^1 f(x,y)\ dxdy$$; can I easily generalize it to prove that $A=B?$

Comment: @Joe first of what you have written is not true. But if you were to fix it then yes it would explain why $A=B$. Like we have discussed before, this is called Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @Joe No. Do it yourself, this is a basic exercise in multivariable calculus, which you should be capable of given that you are studying electromagnetism.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Can you please show how exactly Fubini's theorem applies here?

Comment: @Joe It might be, but I'd like to know exactly how it is.